# How to add remote includes to a synchronized eclipse project for correct indexing?

Tags: linux, eclipse, include

I have created a synchronized project in Eclipse so that I can develop on my Windows workstation without the overhead caused by running eclipse on our company's build server.  However, the problem I'm having is that the indexer is using my Cygwin includes for things such as the stdlib which aren't the ones I wanted to include.  Is there a way to include remote includes from the linux build server for things like the std lib?  The only idea I have right now would be to create a mapped cifs mount to my windows machine that has access to the header files, however I don't know if that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at ["Remote Include Paths"](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.ptp.doc.user/html/sync.html) (bottom of page). Let us know on the ptp-users mailing-list if it doesn't work.